# Linux hanging at boot after fsck

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, fsck

Apologies for the bad photo but it's a big hassle to type it out as a dualboot user:

[image]

It hangs there for ages, no matter how long I leave it. I've had this twice and the first time I reinstalled. Both happened after restarting after installing NVIDIA drivers (ensuring that the installation finished first)

Tried manually doing the fsdk from a livecd and it didn't help the problem.

[image]

Comment: What is your graphics adapter? Which drivers did you install and how?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: I can't exactly remember which drivers I installed. I have 2 NVIDIA GTX 760s in SLI. It was some single terminal command to install some Steam OpenGL dependency. Will post output in a minute when I switch over

Comment: Here's the output for the command - again, sorry for the abhorrent photo quality: http://i.imgur.com/mP1wsOZ.jpg

Comment: Do you have 2 Nvidia cards?

Comment: Yes, I do. Two 760s

Answer (score 1):

You need to install proprietary Nvidia drivers. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

and reboot.

Comment: On my rescue cd thing it apt-get doesn't work (unknown command). Bearing in mind that the only way I've been able to access the console is this bootable USB, (recovery mode even hangs), how should I go about executing this command?

Comment: boot with `nomodeset` http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it  Then install the driver.

Comment: Is it just the general pendrive/live installation that works (I have a similar thing with another distro - debian, and was wondering if I could save some time and use that), or should I specifically use Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi can you help me? So when I boot into the live installation, I need network drivers to get the package. How can I include network drivers with the live install?

Comment: You need network drivers?  How old is that dinosaur of a computer you have?

Answer (score 0):

To all users from future

**Solution**:

IN **GRUB** click **e** and in wall of text replace :

```
quiet splash
```

with

```
nomodeset
```

(RUN ctrl+x) This is temporary to make it permanent use **grub-customizer**

It should run now.

If you are stuck in login loop, do this:

First in tty (ctrl + alt + f1)

```
sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*
```

ctrl+alt+f7 to go back, log in and:

https://askubuntu.com/a/848668/657988

This was the only answer that help me install newest drivers on GTX960M