# Internet does not work in tty

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, nvidia, tty

I did a clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04 and fully updated the system via terminal. After that, I installed nVidia driver downloaded from its official page. Now I'm stuck in infamous login-loop and I can work only with tty. I think solution from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762831/ubuntu-16-stuck-in-login-loop-after-installing-nvidia-364-drivers) would work for me, but there's the problem - the internet doesn't work, so I can't finish `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. Neither Wi-Fi nor USB tethering from phone works.

Here are outputs for commands I tried:

```
ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

---

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
```

---

```
rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Better to just remove whatever Nvidia drivers you installed: `sudo apt purge nvidia*` and start over. If you're unsure about how to correctly install Nvidia drivers and especially what **version** to choose from, please post anew question.

Comment: Not what I wanted, but still better than login loop, so thanks. Do you think  I should also delete modprob file that nVidia installer created and reinstall  Nouveau driver?

Comment: ??? *How* exactly have you installed those drivers?

Comment: I downloaded .run file from nVidia official page,  went to tty, used `sudo service lightdm stop` to stop X server, and run the installer. And then I did what installer wanted me to do (remove Nouveau, and let it add modprob file to automatically disable it in case if it was installed again). I knew nVidia drivers usually bring problems, that's why I did it on clean installation,  but I hoped I will be able to somehow make it work.

Comment: Not surprisingly (expected actually), you used the *not recommended* method. Nvidia drivers are available directly in the Ubuntu repositories (or PPAs if a newer version is needed). Now, you may need to run the Nvidia installer again as I believe it'll give the option to uninstall. No, Nvidia drivers usually don't bring problems unless you install a wrong version.

Comment: The command should be `sudo ~/installation_file.run --uninstall` where *installation_file* must match the name in the file you downloaded from Nvidia.