# Cannot change brightness on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, brightness, msi

I recently re-installed Ubuntu on my MSI GP62 laptop. However, I cannot change the brightness. I have tried many things, including booting with acpi_backlight=vendor and similar combinations.

It should be noted that the output of

```
ls /sys/class/backlight
```

is empty. Perhaps as a result, xbacklight and other applications do not work. I am also using the Intel drivers/nouveau. I tried various versions of the Nvidia drivers, but they all result in a login loop, similar to this: [Ubuntu 16 Stuck in Login Loop after Installing Nvidia 364 Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762831/ubuntu-16-stuck-in-login-loop-after-installing-nvidia-364-drivers).

Output of lspci -vnn |grep VGA:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics [8086:191b] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

I am also using the nomodeset kernel parameter - without it I cannot get to the login screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked was downgrading to Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I've a **MSI GT62VR** with the NVIDIA (375) drivers and brightness working fine in Ubuntu 16.04. I followed the instructions in Step 1 in this link: http://www.castoriscausa.com/posts/ge62vr-mint-gtx1060