# black screen on Suspend

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend

My laptop is asus vivobook X556UQ. I have integrated intel graphic card and nvidia geforce 940mx.

After installing nvidia drivers and nvidia x server I have black screen when I awake laptop after suspend I get a weird error.

The screen is completely black, except for one line of code:

> [   44.351019] rtc_cmos 00:01: Alarms can be up to one month in the future

The only solution is to long-press the physical power button until the machine shuts down.

Comment: Look this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367382

Comment: Thank you @Redbob for your answer. Actually, that guy hasn't solved his problem. He just switched back to nouveau driver.

Comment: I already experienced that. NVIDIA proprietary drivers not always coexist pacifically to hardware they are proposed to do. Good that you got solved that. You could put it as an answer - with details of course - so it will be useful to other users.

Comment: @Sadman Do you have an M.2 PCIe NVMe-enabled SSD installed?

Comment: Switching to Intel (Power Saving Mode) did not work for me. I had to uninstall the 'recommended' Nvidia drivers and use Nouveau drivers instead.

Answer (score 4):

This solution works for me. Ubuntu 16.04, Asus laptop.

> Open Applications -> System Tools -> Administration -> NVIDIA X Server Settings
>
> Choose PRIME Profiles and then click Intel (Power Saving Mode)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the nvidia drivers, read this post: [SUSPEND , RESUMING and WAKEUP with nvidia370.28](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/969433). It tells how to configure your driver to work propely at wakening up from hibernate and suspend.

If you have any issue with looping at login screen, [ubuntu stuck at login loop after nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762831/ubuntu-16-stuck-in-login-loop-after-installing-nvidia-364-drivers)

Comment: It may be helpful to summarize the most important information in the first link you provided, in case the site is taken down in the future or the link breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, though I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. In my case, I solved the problem by switching from Gnome to Gnome Wayland. I don't know exactly why but it became a no longer issue. You might consider trying it.

Another option is to change the primary setting from Nvidia to Intel. You can easily do that by typing

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

in the terminal.