# Can't Resume after suspend Ubuntu 22.0,4 RTX 3070

Tags: boot, nvidia, suspend

Hi everyone I am using Ubuntu 22.0.4 with kernal version 5.19.0-35-generic and RTX 3070. I have tried multiple solutions to fix black screen issue after suspend but none of them are working.

1. I have tried to enable/disable nvidia suspend and resume service
2. add nomdeset in grub and set nouveau.blacklist=1
3. tried nvidia-470, 510, 525 and 515
   Currently I am using nvidia-515 driver can anyone please help me with a possible solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try using the 5.15 GA kernel?  Did you try ..... ie. unless you specifically tell us what you tried, how are we to know what you meant by "*tried multiple solutions*"?  Please provide details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [black screen on Suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954315/black-screen-on-suspend)

Comment: I did not try 5.15 will do thanks

Comment: Try to use X11 instead of Wayland if it isn't already switched.

Comment: I have tried x11 didn't work. Also tried switching to lightdm but no luck