# Ubuntu Nvidia Drivers and Login Loop

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, login

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7000, which has an NVIDIA GTX 1050 graphics card. I'm having a login loop like in [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop), but it only happens when I install the NVIDIA drivers. To install the drivers, I run:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

When I remove them with:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

it starts working again, so I can login.

These solutions did not work for me:

[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

[Ubuntu 16 Stuck in Login Loop after Installing Nvidia 364 Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762831/ubuntu-16-stuck-in-login-loop-after-installing-nvidia-364-drivers)

Also installing `nvidia-prime` did not help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using the software and updates option in Ubuntu.
There is an option to add additional drivers and in my it shows to install the recommended driver.Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/default/grub`.

Modify `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='pcie_port_pm=off acpi_backlight=none acpi_osi=Linux acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"'
```