# Stuck in an infinite login loop on Ubuntu 18.04 on both the GUI and Shell login options

Tags: login

Like the title says, I can’t login. Whenever I do, I just get a black screen and get taken back to the login screen. I’ve tried ctrl+alt+f2 but logging in through that also puts me in a login loop.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so adding it as an answer.

I had a login issue on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS because of the conflict between display manager and nvidia graphic drivers. Please note that the default display manager for Ubuntu 18.04 is gdm3 and for Ubuntu 16.04 is LightDM.

Did you try the resources Q&A [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762831/ubuntu-16-stuck-in-login-loop-after-installing-nvidia-364-drivers)?

Can you share more details? What's the make and model of your machine? Did the issue start immediately after a fresh install or just after you ran the software updater?

Edit:

Press Esc as soon as you see the manufacturer's logo (not Ubuntu logo). This is the first thing that shows up on the screen after you press the power button. This should work in all likelihood. I tried it on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine for testing. The official method [here](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) says the same. Once you are able to select advanced options for Ubuntu -> select a line ending with (recovery mode). You should be then able to boot into ubuntu. Fire a terminal and purge the nvidia drivers :-)

Comment: I have an Asus Zenbook with an Nvidia GTX 1050 Max-Q, 16GB DDR4 RAM, and an Intel i7-8565U. I’ve been running Ubuntu for around 2 weeks now perfectly with no issues but this just happened to me out of the blue and I have no idea what’s going on. I also can’t run any terminal commands because I can’t even log in on the terminal.

Comment: Tried logging in with ``CTRL+ALT+F2``?

Comment: Yes. I mentioned that in my post. Same issue

Comment: You can (a) try purging the nvidia drivers by logging in as single user mode (https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-boot-into-rescue-mode-or-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu-18-04/) and maybe try the steps mentioned here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub)
(b) use a live ubuntu usb (bootable iso) to modify the drivers. The answer here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185442/modify-existing-ubuntu-installation-from-usb-live-boot) helped me 2 years ago. Hope it helps! :-)

Comment: Are you able to enter grub when you press Esc when you see the Ubuntu logo?

Comment: I have no grub. I can only log into either my login screen or the BIOS

Comment: Is your Ubuntu install UEFI or legacy? Esc works on legacy.

Comment: Press Esc as soon as you see the manufacturer's logo (not Ubuntu logo). This is the first thing that shows up on the screen after you press the power button. This should work in all likelihood. I tried it on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine. The official method also says the same, [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode].
Once you are able to select advanced options for Ubuntu -> select a line ending with (recovery mode). You should be then able to boot into ubuntu. Purge the nvidia drivers :-)

Comment: I’ll try this in a bit as I’m not at my laptop atm however this was working all fine before and I haven’t updated my drivers recently so I don’t see how this is an Nvidia driver issue

Comment: Yes you're right, given you haven't updated lightdm is less likely a cause. It might as well be another issue. Once you are able to login to a shell you might as well check your ~/.xsessions-errors or ~/.profile etc. for any clues.